# Ruby, Array.select with number of elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I would like to get the first 2 elements that are bigger than 3.

I can do:

```
elements = []

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].each do |element|
  elements << element if element > 3
  break if elements.size == 2
end

puts elements
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Is there something in the Ruby core like `Array.select(num_elements, &block)`?

Comment: Why did not you choose `arr.select { |z| z > 3 }[2]` ?

Comment: @ray because in my production scenario the filter computation is very expensive and the number of elements can be thousands. So I want to break the loop as soon I have achieve the minimum desirable amount

Comment: I got your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there. Just use `break` with a parameter:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].each_with_object([]) do |element, acc|
  acc << element if element > 3
  break acc if acc.size >= 2
end
```

Another way to accomplish it, would be to use [`Enumerator::Lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator/Lazy.html) with `array.lazy.select`, or an explicit `Enumerator` instance with `Enumerable#take` (here it’s a definite overkill, posting mostly for educational purposes.)

```
enum =
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    i = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].each
    loop { i.next.tap { |e| y << e if e > 3 } }
  end
enum.take(2)
#⇒ [4, 5]
```

*Sidenote:* both examples above would stop traversing the input as soon as two elements are found.

Comment: Why don't you use to_enum method instead of each?

Comment: `each` without a block calls `to_enum` under the hood.

Comment: Yes, but here your intention is to convert so why calling each rather than to_enum? That would explicitly tells us as well.

Comment: the part of `stop traversing the input as soon as two elements are found` is the key here.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

p a.filter {|x| x > 3}.first(2)
```

Or

```
p a.select{|x| x > 3}.first(2)
```

output

```
[4, 5]
```

As Cary suggest, the given below code wouldn't be a performance hit if  array is bigger, it would stop executing further if 2 elements are found

```
a.lazy.select{|x| x > 3}.first(2)
```

Comment: ...or `a.lazy.select{|x| x > 3}.first(2)` to bail out as soon as the first two have been found.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's exactly something I am thinking now. Thanks. Will update the answer now.

Comment: I prefer that any acknowledgement of readers' contributions to answers be confined to comments (and that such acknowledgements are generally not needed), in order to keep answers focused on the question. In the same way you don't see books and articles littered with acknowledgements of which readers of drafts suggested which changes.

Comment: Okay sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just for having a couple of options more..

```
ary.each_with_object([]) { |e, res| res << e if e > 3 && res.size < 2 }
```

or

```
ary.partition { |e| e > 3 }.first.first(2)
```

Comment: Wow super. Amazing idea.

Comment: This traverses the whole array, which might be a bit underperformant for `[1, 1, *1..Float::INFINITY]`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, I'm aware. But I'm unsure about `partition`. I've not been able to find how to break when `res.size < 2`, `and break if` was returning `nil`. But I'm learning it right now from your answer: `{ |e, res| res << e if e > 3; break res if res.size == 2 }` :).

Comment: If you are unsure about `partition`, there is a simple way to ensure: `(1..10).partition { |e| puts e; e > 3 }.first.first(2)`. To escape sooner you need a lazy enumerator.